# Problem using ffmpeg in streaming mode on aac files created by Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm recording audio clips in Android using `aac`, exporting the files to my Mac and then trying to decode them using `ffmpeg`. It works fine in file mode but fails in streaming mode with the following error. It seems that consistently short files work fine but long files (2 minutes or longer) fail. Bug in Android, `ffmpeg` or am I using `ffmpeg` incorrectly?

Thanks,
Dror

```
ffmpeg  -f m4a -i -  bad.wav <  3e4cfa9ff60b48d885947291fbfb981b.m4a

stream 0, offset 0x1916: partial file
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I figured it out.  The m4a file has some header information that is being put at the end of the file by the Android media player because it is a streaming application.  ffmpeg in streaming mode needs that header information to be near the beginning of the file.  Fixing the file using ffmpeg -acodec copy -movflags faststart works for me.